# How to recognize File or Folder from dropbox APi

Tags: iphone, dropbox

Hello I am using dropbox api and displaying meta data from dropbox account..

I want  to differentiate files and folders from loaded data..because I want to show next level if there is folder and if there is file I don't want to show next View

my code to load data

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata {

    [self.metaArray release];
    self.metaArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init ];

    for (DBMetadata *child in metadata.contents) {

        NSString *folderName = [[child.path pathComponents] lastObject];
        [self.metaArray addObject:folderName];



    }



    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];


}
```

[image: Like this]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Dropbox Developer Docs](http://www.dropbox.com/developers/docs) the metadata includes a property called `is_dir` which should allow you to determine whether the particular item is a directory or not.

Looking at the header of `DBMetaData` it is indeed exposed as a property

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL isDirectory;
```

So you can just do a simple test like so

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata
{
    if (metadata.isDirectory) {
        // handle directory here
    } else {
        // handle file here
    }
}
```

With regards pushing views based on whether or not an entry is a directory, you could subclass `UITableViewCell` and add an `isDirectory` property. Instead of adding just the name to `self.metaArray` you could add a dictionary containing both the name and the value of `isDirectory`. Then in your table view datasource where you populate the cells you'd set the `isDirectory` property of the `UITableViewCell` based on the same property in the appropriate dictionary from the array. Finally, in the table view delegate method

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

you can get the selected cell using the `indexPath` and then test the `isDirectory` property and based on it's value take the appropriate action.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You would need to either test before you enter the `for` loop for top level directories, or use `child.isDirectory` inside the `for` instead of `metadata.isDirectory`

Comment: And one more question. There might be folder in folder..So how much hiearachy should I manage?

Comment: That's entirely up to you and the requirements of your project. But it should be fairly trivial because you can just reuse the same code, meaning the same controller and view etc and just pass the appropriate `child` as the data source each time you drop down a level.

Answer (score 4):

Using the API V2 of Dropbox with the Dropbox SDK is:

```
DropboxClient *client = [DropboxClientsManager authorizedClient];
[[client.filesRoutes listFolder:path]
 response:^(DBFILESListFolderResult *result, DBFILESListFolderError *routeError, DBRequestError *error) {
     if (result) {

         for (DBFILESMetadata *entry in result.entries) {
             if ([entry isKindOfClass:[DBFILESFileMetadata class]]) {
                 DBFILESFileMetadata *fileMetadata = (DBFILESFileMetadata *)entry;
                 NSLog(@"File: %@", fileMetadata.name);
             } else if ([entry isKindOfClass:[DBFILESFolderMetadata class]]) {
                 DBFILESFolderMetadata *folderMetadata = (DBFILESFolderMetadata *)entry;
                 NSLog(@"Folder: %@", folderMetadata.name);
             }
         }
     }
```